# Dynamically fill selection-screen parameter on change

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

Suppose I have a selection-screen block with two parameters. I want to dynamically fill the second parameter based on what the user inputs in the first, for instance by querying a table to find the expected value for the key field in parameter 1.

As an example, say I have a program that does something for a combination of order number (`p_aufnr`) and WBS element (`p_wbs`). Instead of asking the user to provide both, I can determine one of them from the PSPEL field on the AUFK table. However, I still want to show this field to the user after he inputs his order number so he can verify that the WBS element is correct.

I've managed to do this by using the `AT SELECTION SCREEN ON p_aufnr` event to assign a value to `p_wbs`. This event is processed when the user presses enter. However, I can only ever get it to work once. So if the user enters an order number, realises from the retrieved WBS element that he made a mistake and changes it, the second parameter never changes. Even though the `AT SELECTION SCREEN` event is processed in the debugger, the parameter is not updated.

Am I not supposed to use this event for my scenario? If so, how would I then implement this sort of dynamic selection screen?

Forgot to add a code sample. The following report illustrates my issue: after entering a value in `p_netw` and pressing enter, p_wbs is filled with the value 1. However, if you press enter again the `AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON` routine is processed but the value for p_wbs is not updated, while `lv_count` is.

```
DATA: lv_count    TYPE i.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK main.
PARAMETERS: p_netw    TYPE aufnr OBLIGATORY MODIF ID auf.
PARAMETERS: p_wbs     TYPE i MODIF ID psp.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK   main.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_netw.
  ADD 1 TO lv_count.
  p_wbs = lv_count.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  PERFORM main.


FORM main.
  WRITE: 'The value reached ', lv_count.
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: Could you please add a minimal working example that demonstrates the issue? This will make it much easier to understand the problem you're facing and provide an answer.

Comment: Example added, I hope this adequately demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the data is not written back to the screen if you update the field in the field-specific block. If you move the field update from `AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_netw` to the global `AT SELECTION-SCREEN` event, it works. Don't ask me why, though - this seems to  a case of undocumented system behaviour...

```
DATA: lv_count    TYPE i.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK main.
PARAMETERS: p_netw    TYPE aufnr OBLIGATORY MODIF ID auf.
PARAMETERS: p_wbs     TYPE i MODIF ID psp.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK   main.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_netw.
  ADD 1 TO lv_count.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.
  p_wbs = lv_count.
```

Comment: I guess the `ON x` events weren't intended for this use case. Unfortunate that this isn't documented as you say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a PAI (process after input) module on your screen which then takes the new p_aufnr and finds the appropriate p_wbs - probably exactly like your at selection screen event. You will then CALL SCREEN ### <-- your screen number to display the data on your screen. Without any code to work off thats all i can help with.